# picking Android word suggestions programmatically

Tags: android

How can I pick Android Word suggestions programmatically from Android?

Comment: Do want to say that you wanna implement AutoComplete Functionality?

Comment: no dear , I dont want to implement functioanlity , i just want to pick already stored words programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoCompleteTextView for example:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.countries);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
     AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
     "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
 };
```

}
or use this link:
[How to include suggestions in Android Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031402/how-to-include-suggestions-in-android-keyboard)

Comment: Please share complete example............... i needs code..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then you can use a database like Realm and store your data into the DB. Then fetch the data in EditText's addTextChangedListener.

```
edtFolderName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

  RealmResults <ObjectClass> results = realm.where(ObjectClass.class)
                                              .like("name",s.toString+"*") // feild name
                                              .findAll();

    //You can display this values inside your spinner                                              
 }

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

 }
});
```