# Is there a way to get the suggestions from keyboard in android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-custom-keyboard, gboard

Can we get all the suggestions shown in any keyboard on android while typing?

If no, is there any alternate way of doing it?

I tried with SpellCheckerSessionListener, didn't succeed.

Comment: Answer from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031402/how-to-include-suggestions-in-android-keyboard)

Comment: there is no way and should be no way. The reason is that suggestions are based on the user frequent words used, and if you could get them - it would be a provacy problem.