# Text Prediction functionality for Custom Keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, android-custom-keyboard, predictive

I have developed a **Basic Keyboard**.

**Here** is how it looks :

[image]

Now, I want to add the **Predictive Text Functionality**.

[image]

**I did some research** and found some information about **Backend** part of it. Which showed **how the keyboard can learn from user to user**.

But I **could not** find the **Front End Part (XML)** of it Anywhere.

If this question **seems hoax** to you, **please let me know**.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to below solution :[How to include suggestions in Android Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031402/how-to-include-suggestions-in-android-keyboard)

ou can use the static method UserDictionary.Words.addWord(....): Link

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
// On JellyBean & above, you can provide a shortcut and an explicit Locale 
UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "MadeUpWord", 10, "Mad", Locale.getDefault());
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
 UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "MadeUpWord", 10, UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE_TYPE_CURRENT);
}
```

You will need to add this permission to your manifest:

Added words will appear in

> Settings > Language & input > Personal dictionary

.

Comment: Thank you, @Chetan Joshi. Though, my main problem is Front End Part.

I read the post which you've given the link of. And I read that. But What I was and What I am confused about is Front End !

That post led me to some links which covered Back End Part which I understood.

I couldn't find any example, post, blog, video which covers the front end.

Now, I am only concerned about FRONT END !

And I tried come layouts with KeyboardView. Every time I got error that gave me conclusion that I can't use any layout with KeyboardView.

So, How do I merge KeyboardView and SuggestionStrip ?